what may be the cause of fatal: bad objet refs/heads/main
how do i solve this :"error: refs/heads/main does not point to a valid object!
error: Could not read 5af3c0030e9328002e456c895f5c4005d3d6360f
fatal: bad object refs/heads/main
fatal: failed to run repack" ?
git remote set-head origin --auto
git gc
